# Is there a way to know what fonts to use on the web?

Tags: fonts

I know that all computers and Operating systems (windows,linux,os etc.) come with there own set of fonts,  Is there a list of the most common fonts that are most likely to be available on a persons computer.  I want to use some nice fonts on my site but it's hard to find what is a good choice that the most amount of people will be able to see.

Comment: This might be a good question to ask at http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good sites are here:

http://www.csstypeset.com/

http://www.typetester.org/ - powerful

Answer (score 3):

Reasonable list here: http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html